# Find a directory only contained within a certain folder

Tags: bash, find

I have a directory structure like:

```
foo
 |__bar
     |__bin
     |   |__tmp
     |
     |__bez
         |__tmp
```

I need to find the **tmp** directory in *bin/tmp*, but not the one in *bez/tmp*. It seems to me that *find* only operates on the name of one directory or file at a time. Is there a command that will return me the path to the tmp directory in *bin*, but not the one in *bez*? It's a bonus if the command finds all bin/tmp folders, as there may be many in the directory tree.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find ./foo/ -type d -path '*/bin/tmp'
```